# Is there a way to make the alarm clock much much louder?

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to treat my iPhone as an alarm clock. But, **it's not working**. I'm not a light sleeper and the iPhone "alarm clock" does not have that kind of explosive power my traditional alarm clock has.

Is there a way to make the alarm clock much much louder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest that you **try a few alert tones** to see if any of them give you better performance. Volume dynamics vary from alert to alert. By going into the click app and tapping Alarm > Edit and selecting any alarm you will see the settings that you can change. One of the settings you can change for a given alarm is Sound. Tap this option to select the tone you would like to use.

One tone you might find more to your liking is the one titled "Alarm" — this tone is much more "explosive" than the standard "Marimba tone.

You could also **try recording your own tones in GarageBand**. GarageBand has a project type for iPhone Ringtones. When you create your own ringtone you have much more control over the specifics of the ringtone and can even do things to increase the gain on the tone itself.

Of course none of these tips will do anything to increase the actual power of the built in speakers (which are necessarily small). One thing you could do to help in that regard is to **think carefully about where you place your phone**. Placing your phone in a glass cup at night (while a bit dangerous in the morning when you go groping for it) can increase the volume significantly.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 13):

Why yes - there is an accessory for just that purpose.

[image: analog tele-phonographers]

Several musical instrument recyclers/artists - notably [Christopher Locke](http://heartlessmachine.com/section/220780_Analog_Tele_Phonographer.html) - make and sell a selection of iPhone, iPad and other amplifiers that will make your iOS alarm clock much louder.

Answer (score 6):

There is not much you can do with the built in speakers of the iPhone. My biggest suggestion would be using external speakers connected through an auxiliary cable or something similar.

Comment: Just be careful that the external speakers to not go to sleep during the night if using this method.

Answer (score 5):

You could try...

1. Plugging in some speakers or connecting a bluetooth speaker
2. Putting your phone in a container (like a Tupperware or a bowl) to focus the sound
3. Turning up your ringer volume all the way

You could also try downloading one of the following apps:

- [Loud Alarm Clock FREE](https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/loud-alarm-clock-free-best/id593567385?mt=8&at=10lJ7Y&ct=StackOverflow)
- [Alarm Clock Free for iOS 8](https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/alarm-clock-free-for-ios-8/id749124884?mt=8&at=10lJ7Y&ct=StackOverflow)
- [SpinMe Alarm Clock - Guaranteed Wake Up for Deep Sleepers](https://geo.itunes.apple.com/us/app/spinme-alarm-clock-guaranteed/id607979227?mt=8&at=10lJ7Y&ct=StackOverflow)

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Clock
2. Go to Alarm
3. Edit/Create Alarm
4. Go to Sound
5. Select Sound
6. Turn up volume with side up button while sound is playing
7. BAM!

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can increase the volume. Go to settings, then sounds the look for ringer and alerts. Slide the bar to increase or decrease volume. If you have an iPhone this will also increase the volume of your ringtone.

Comment: This doesn't adequately answer the question. Probably in this case, the answer is "No" -- unless the iPhone user connects their phone to an external speaker